# Insert.da.Cursor, Error - Sequence size must match size of row

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I'm working on this script which creates a table within a geodatabase. It then grabs the unique values from a list and attempts to insert them into the table using an **Insert Cursor**.

I get the Error

```
Runtime error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 25, in <module>
TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row
```

My code is as follows:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\BaseLayer\UniqueValue.gdb"

## Designate the input layer.
featureclass = "Q:\Admin\IP_AnnoTools\Intermediates\Intersects\Output_Hydro_Line_Intersect.shp"## Parameter
field = "FEATURE_TY"## Parameter
valueList = []
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(featureclass)
for row in rows:
    valueList.append(row.getValue(field))

uniqueSet = set(valueList)
uniqueList = list(uniqueSet)
uniqueList.sort()


arcpy.CreateTable_management("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\BaseLayer\UniqueValue.gdb", "unique")
arcpy.AddField_management("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\BaseLayer\UniqueValue.gdb\unique","UNIQUE_VAL","TEXT","","","100")
unique = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\BaseLayer\UniqueValue.gdb\unique"

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(unique,("UNIQUE_VAL"))

for uv in uniqueList:
    cursor.insertRow(uv)

del cursor
print uniqueList
del rows
del row
```

My output when I print my list is:

```
[u'FLOW-ARB-MANUAL', u'LAKE-REP-PRI', u'RIV-MAJ-REP-PRI', u'STR-INDEF', u'STR-PER', u'STR-RECUR']
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to insert a list, you're inserting a single value.

```
for uv in uniqueList:
    cursor.insertRow(uv)
```

should be

```
for uv in uniqueList:
    cursor.insertRow([uv])
```

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to put a string into the insertRow method, but that method expects a list or tuple.  The insertrow method first counts the items in the list or tuple to see if the item count matches the row field count, but since a string item count is most likely 0 it always fails to match up with the field count of the row (i.e., 1).  So instead try converting each string value into a list with a single string value.  That way the count of items in the list will match the field count (1 string item in the list will match 1 string field in the row).

So modify your code to see if this works:

```
for uv in uniqueList:
    cursor.insertRow([uv])
```